# bat file that findstr string1 AND string2

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I am trying to do the following: Search through all txt file in Temp that starts with 'Micro' and find if the following two strings exists in any of them. I need to find both strings in 1 file.

Currently I've got:`enter code here`

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp
findstr /N /C:"action: Uninstall" /C:"Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No" Micro*.log >results.txt
if %errorlevel%==1 (
robocopy C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop results.txt
) else (
echo matches found
)
```

but this is using OR. I found that I need to use .* for AND, but the following simple doesn't work:

```
findstr /N /C:"action: Uninstall".*/C:"Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No" Micro*.log
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong. :/

Cheers,
Geri

Comment: sorry, not all txt, but all .log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "string1=action: Uninstall"
set "string2=Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No"
set "files=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Micro*.log"

findstr /m /c:"%string1%" "%files%" | findstr /f:/ /m /c:"%string2%"
```

Get the list of files that contain the first string and use this list to search the second string.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /M /C:"action: Uninstall" Micro*.log') do (
   findstr /N /C:"Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No" "%%a"
)
```

Comment: Will that work?  Won't the first findstr will just pipe the lines that it finds to the second findstr. Meaning that the second findstr will never match because it is only looking at the result of the first findstr.

Comment: not sure why... but it is not working. Should I state again the Micro*.log at the end of the second string.?

Comment: I've got the following:       >findstr /N /C:"action: Uninstall" Micro*.lo
g   | findstr /C:"Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No"  1>results.txt

C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp>if 1 == 1 (robocopy C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppDa
ta\Local\Temp C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop results.txt )  else (echo matches f
ound )

Comment: I basically need to find both strings in a file. and handle it if I cannot find any of them. But my pass will be "I 've found both". If one ot both are not matching I will be having a fail. and I need to look for the exact strings... :/

Comment: You may do some tests with each individual `findstr`: test the first one and check the result, then redirect that result to a file and test the second `findstr` with that file...

Comment: @DavidRuhmann: precisely: the second findstr search only in the lines that contain the first string, so the result are the lines that contain _both_ strings.

Comment: @Aacini I think the OP wants it to detect when the strings are on separate lines as well.  Just find the files that contain both strings not just the files that contain both strings on the same line.

Comment: @user2458507: The question is not clear about this point. You should said "I need to find both strings in 1 file _even in separated lines_".

Comment: Excuse me. Just to let you know that I edited my answer 4 hours ago in order to achieve what you want: find two strings in the same file...

Comment: thanks a lot about that. It worked partially. I've tested it quite a lot and only the second statement get checked for some reason ""Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No"". If I don't have the first string, then somehow it always passes. Still, thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean that `findstr /M /C:"action: Uninstall" Micro*.log` show the names of some files even if they does not contain the string? `findstr` don't work that way; you may check this point directly in a command line... Note that the second `findstr` is executed on the files displayed by the first one